# Null pointer Exception in defining method from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to call a method from an activity to another activity but i give null pointer exception .

SidebarClass.java

```
public class SidebarClass extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

public void Sidebar(final Context c) {

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(c, generateData());
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList
            .setOnItemClickListener(new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        android.view.View view, int position, long id) {

                    switch (position) {

                    case 1:
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(c, Map.class);
                        startActivity(i1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(c,
                                Basket.class);
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
}

private ArrayList<Model> generateData() {
    ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    models.add(new Model("TimiT "));

    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.home, "home", 1));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.basket, "basket", 2));

    return models;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SidebarClass side = new SidebarClass();
    side.Sidebar(getBaseContext());

  }
}
```

Logcat

```
    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.timittest/com.example.timittest.MainActivity}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at  
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at 
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:79
3)
05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):     at 
    android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)

   05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):  at
   com.example.tools.SidebarClass.Sidebar(SidebarClass.java:29)

  05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):   at

  com.example.timittest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)

  05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):   at

  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

  05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):   at
  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  05-30 13:30:29.897: E/AndroidRuntime(6850):   at
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Comment: **do not instantiate an Activity manually. Use startActivity(new Intent(this, SideBarClass.class));**

Comment: although technically you need to read up on how to use `Fragment`s.

Comment: Please watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWpEh9k8i7Q&index=6&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR2K_Sav7q8&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=7 and use what you've learned.

Comment: @hdiz can you able to post your layout file in which your `drawer_layout` and  `listview` placed.

Comment: Make your `MainActivity` extend `SideBar` class instead of `Activity`.

Comment: What is line 29 of SidebarClass.java?

Comment: I can't do this!!! i have plenty of things into main activity

Comment: @hidz please see the answer, I have posted

Comment: I should have added the fourth part because that's where the true magic happens. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBKpsGar5mc&index=9&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

Answer (score 1):

```
SidebarClass side = new SidebarClass();
side.Sidebar(getBaseContext());
```

This is a very bad idea. You should NEVER instantiate an Activity manually. It appears that your design has some problems. Most likely, your `SidebarClass` should **not** extend `Activity`. Just remove this part. I also suggest that you do some research to find the suggested practices for creating a `DrawerLayout`.

With that said, the underlying problem will probably still be in your code. Note the following line in your logcat:

```
at
```

com.example.tools.SidebarClass.Sidebar(SidebarClass.java:29)

This says that the error occurs in the `SidebarClass.java` file on line 29. You need to look at this line and figure out why it causes the NPE.

Comment: He doesn't even need an Activity though, what he wants is a DrawerLayout and two fragments.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, the OP certainly needs to read about the various Android API classes which are available to do what he wants. I didn't dig that deep into his code to see what he's really trying to do.

Comment: I know how can Intent from an Activity to another . what i need is to use sidebar method in all activities that i have!! because of this i want to create a class that has sidebar method then i use every where i want.

Comment: @hdiz My first sentence is still correct. NEVER create an Activity manually. Since you are trying to create a DrawerLayout, you need to research the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Before taking the handle of DrawerLayout and ListView. You must take the handle of View in which these controls are placed.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null, false);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: error solved but sidebar doesn't have any element!!! the other thing is in sidebar class i don't have content view , so how can i define layout in inflater ??? my layout is in activity_main !!

Comment: for test i use activity_main.xml !!

Comment: Yes, Because in your SideBar you have no access of activity_main as you have not set the layout for that activity. So if you take the handle by inflating it you may have access to the controls that are in activit_main.

Comment: my problem not solved. i said error gone but element of sidebar doesn't exist!

Comment: @hdiz Your sidebar should have its own layout file independent of any activity. If you have a new problem other than the NullPointerException that you asked about here, you should start a new question explaining your new code. Be sure to include the relevant layout files.

Comment: @hidz Now that is the separate question. The problem is you are using activity for drawer layout try to use fragment. For testing implement the functionality of `SideBarActivity` into `MainActivity`.

Comment: @hidz Please accept this answer and start a new thread for your new problem.

Comment: Thanks for everyone , I should change my idea . It doesn't reasonable at all .

Comment: @hidz you should accept this answer. As what you asked you got solved.